# Cannot access 'TAG': it is invisible (private in supertype) in 'AppCompatActivity'

Tags: android-activity

I am a beginner in android programming. I'm currently using android studio 3.2.1.
I am trying to monitor the different states of an android activity in log. I have written the code shown below, but I keep receiving the error message:

> Cannot access 'TAG': it is invisible (private in supertype) in 'AppCompatActivity'.

Even after searching, I cannot figure the error. Can some one help?
Code:

---

```
package com.cooperation.bestech.test1

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log;

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
     private static final String TAG = "MyMessage";

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        Log.i(TAG, "onStart");
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        Log.i(TAG, "onPause");
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        Log.i(TAG, "onResume");
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        Log.i(TAG, "onStop");
    }

    override fun onRestart() {
        super.onRestart()
        Log.i(TAG, "onRestart");
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy");
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
        Log.i(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState");
    }
}
```

Comment: Which programming language are you using? Java, Kotlin, or _Jatlin_?

Comment: The `:` way for inheritance, and `override` instead of `@Override` shows it may be Kotlin; the `;` is both Kotlin and Java acceptable (but not necessary for Kotlin); the declaration for `TAG` may be Java way. So which programming language are you using now?

Comment: Actually the language is kotlin, my android studio 3.2.1 starts projects only in kotlin. Meanwhile the tutorial am using is in java. That question opened my eyes. Please can I set android studio to launch java projects instead of the default kotlin?

Answer (score 2):

Since the original question is written in Kotlin (from comment), ignore the request of "launch Java project instead of the default Kotlin" may be a better solution.

And, applying the correct way to declare and assign a variable, your code segment should be like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val TAG = "MyMessage"
```

Comment: Thank you is an understatement, I'm very grateful. it worked well for me

Answer (score 2):

`import android.content.ContentValues.TAG`

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are using Kotlin.So you need to define TAG in kotlin way:

```
In Kotlin constants located in the companion object:
class MyClass {
    companion object {
        private val TAG = "ClassName"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I now know the language is kotlin while my tutorial is in java. I will like to use java first before migrating to kotlin later. Please can I set android studio to launch java projects instead of the default kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario the variable was private, I make it public and solved.